# Convert JTS Geometry to ElasticSearch Geometry in Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jts

I'm trying to find a way to convert a JTS Geometry to an ElasticSeach Geometry in order to make a geo query, but I didn't find a convenient way.

Using ElasticSearch 7.11.1 with Java API, to make a geospatial query, I should use a

```
    GeoShapeQueryBuilder
```

returned by

```
QueryBuilders.geoShapeQuery(String, org.elasticsearch.geometry.Geometry)
```

method.

But, in my project, I'm using the JTS geometry (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTS_Topology_Suite), where a geometry is an instance of class:

```
org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry
```

Obviously, I can't cast JTS Geometry to ElasticSearch Geometry, but I should convert the instance is somw way.

Has anyone encountered similar problem?
Thank you very much

Comment: please, provide the code or explain what you have tried, so we can help

Answer (score 1):

You can get coordinates from your jts.Geometry object and build whatever elasticsearch.Geometry you need e.g for Polygon you would write something like this:

```
val coordinates = geometry.coordinates
val mappedCoordinates = coordinates.map { Coordinate(it.x, it.y) }
val toPolygonGeometry = PolygonBuilder(CoordinatesBuilder().coordinates(mappedCoordinates)).toPolygonGeometry()
```